Nginx Config: Firefox do not redirect correctly https://www to https://
I did this simple ngninx config to redirect http://example.com, http://www.example.com https://www.example.com to https://example.com
Everything works as expected with chrome, but I noticed Firefox needs the certficate for www.example.com and do not redirect it to https://example.com.
I ideally want to keep only one certificate and taking profit of the redirection.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplecom/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


Chrome may appear to work, but it's not working the way you expect. Your configuration only redirects from http to https. You are missing one of your use cases. The are many examples on SO (including this one) and you will need a certificate for www.example.com to avoid browser errors.
